# How to access variable value present from try block in the catch block in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the type of the value that is given as input in the try block when an exception is raised so that it gives a clear picture to the user as to what input is actually given and what needs to be given instead using the following code snippet in Python -

```
a = None
try:
    a = int(input('Enter a number'))
    print(a)

except ValueError:
    print('Control waited for Integer , but got a {}'.format(type(a)))
```

But unable to access the type of variable 'a' in the except block.
For example: when the user provides the input as True , I'd want the user to know that the control waited for integer but it received a boolean instead.  in python.
locals() function did not help. Any insights ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the `input` from the `int` parsing part, like this:

```
a = input('Enter a number ') # a gets assigned, no matter what
a = int(a) # if not an int, will throw the Exception, but a keeps the value assigned in the previous line
```

In your example, `a` will never get assigned within the `try` block if you don't enter an `int`.

Regarding *where* the `input` part should sit (I mean, outside or inside the `try` block), from a variable assignment perspective that is indifferent, given that in both cases `a` will be part of the *global* scope. Given that - for this specific case - `input` should be benign Exception-wise and won't throw a `ValueError` anyway, it may as well sit outside the `try` block.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the input out of the try except block and you are good.

```py
a = input("Enter, a number")
try:
    a = int(a)
    print(a)

except ValueError:
    print('Control waited for Integer but {a} cannot be casted to int')
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @Simon Hawe 


Every variable , unless user provides integer as the input , will be treated as str giving the type(a) as Control waited for Integer , but got a <class 'str'>.

Also isn't there a way to pass value from try to except? Just brainstorming. .

Comment: What do you mean by pass on? I mean if you do x = somfunction_thatraises() this function will not return anything and hence x will never become a value assigned or created

Answer (score 1):

As others wrote, the in put is not assigned to `a` when the exception is raised.

When you are capturing exception, use a minimal `try` bloc;

```
a = input('Enter a number')
try:
    a = int(a)
except ValueError:
    print('Control waited for Integer , but got a {}'.format(type(a)))
print(a)
```